# RequireJs bundling with modules

Tags: javascript, requirejs, bundling-and-minification

I recently saw an example of how requirejs bundles work(http://vimeo.com/97519516) and got excited. So I'm trying to get the bundling feature to work with my setup and am banging my head on the wall.

Troubleshooting done so far.
The main.js file will be created properly without bundling and defining the comp1 component in the main.js top depenendecy. But when I nest the comp1 dependency and add the bundling options the page1 and page2 bundle never gets created. So it doesn't seem to be an issue with the rest of the configuration. I have also tried this a few different ways. Removing the module and and putting everything in the root of the config. Moving the bundles to the all-config.js. Any ideas on what I could be doing wrong.

all-config.js

```
(function() {
if (typeof requirejs != 'function') {
    requirejs = function(config) { requirejs = config; };
}

requirejs({
   pathes: {
     comp1: "path1",
     comp2: "path2,
     router: "path3"
   }
});
```

build.json

```
 {
"baseUrl": "./",
"appDir": "../src/main/webapp",

"dir": "build",
"mainConfigFile": "app/all-config.js",

 modules: [
    {
       "include": [
          "app/lib/require/require.js"
        ],
        bundles":{
           "page1" : ["comp1"],
           "page2" : ["comp2"]
        }
    }
 ]
}
```

main.js

```
require(['jquery', 'router'],function($){
   //load app
   require(["comp1"],function(comp1){
     var app = new comp1();
   });
});
```

Gruntfile

```
module.exports = function(grunt){

var stripper = require('strip-json-comments');
var buildOptionsFile = grunt.file.read( 'build.json' );
var buildOptions = JSON.parse(stripper(buildOptionsFile) );

grunt.initConfig({
     requirejs: {
        compile: {
            options: buildOptions
        }
    }
});
 .....
};
```

Any ideas on how to get this to work?